# iPhone - track back button event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios4, uinavigationcontroller

I have a tableView which lists the contents of my document directory. I have some zip files in that. If I touch a file in the tableView, the corresponding zip file is unzipped and extracted in a temporary directory(`newFilePath` in my case). The contents unzipped is listed in the next tableView. When I touch the back button, the contents in the directory is listed again.

For example, consider that I have four zip files in my document directory.

songs.zip, videos.zip, files.zip, calculation.zip

When I run the application, all the four files are listed in the tableView. When I touch songs.zip, this file is extracted in the `newFilePath` and its contents are pushed to the next tableView. When I touch back, the previous tableView, i.e, the four files in the document directory are listed again. Everything works perfect.

The problem is, the extracted files in the `newFilePath` remains there itself. They occupy the memory unnecessarily. I want them to be removed from that path when I touch the back button, i.e, I want to make `newFilePath` empty when the back button is touched.

I tried for it. But, no use. I tried `removeItemAtPath:` method in `viewWillAppear:` and also in `viewWillDisappear:`. But it didnt work in both the cases.

Is there any other method to track the action of the back button? I want an event to take place when the back button is touched. So please help me by sharing your ideas. Here is my code for your verification.

This is my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
NSString *filePath = //filePath
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    NSLog(@"File exists at path: %@", filePath);
} else {
    NSLog(@"File does not exists at path: %@", filePath);
}       
ZipArchive *zip = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
NSString *newFilePath = //newFilePath
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:newFilePath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
BOOL result = NO;

if([zip UnzipOpenFile:filePath]) {

    //zip file is there

    if ([zip UnzipFileTo:newFilePath overWrite:YES]) {

        //unzipped successfully

        NSLog(@"Archive unzip Success");

        result= YES;

    } else {

        NSLog(@"Failure To Extract Archive, maybe password?");

    }

} else  {

    NSLog(@"Failure To Open Archive");

}

iDataTravellerAppDelegate *AppDelegate = (iDataTravellerAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//Prepare to tableview.
MyFilesList *myFilesList = [[MyFilesList alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyFilesList" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

//Increment the Current View
myFilesList.CurrentLevel += 1;

viewPushed = YES;
//Push the new table view on the stack
myFilesList.directoryContent = [AppDelegate getTemporaryDirectoryItemList:newFilePath];
[myFilesList setTitle:detailedViewController.strName];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myFilesList animated:YES];
[myFilesList release];
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for creating your own action you need custom back button.But i think viewWillDisAppear also can do solve your problem.

use this code for solving your problem

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 



NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *databaseFile = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newFilePath"];

 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 [fileManager removeItemAtPath:databaseFile error:NULL];
```

This may help you.

**Edit:**

```
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *secondaryDirectoryPath = [secondaryDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"secondary"];

     NSString *databaseFile = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newFilePath"];
```

use these lines in your code if you have directory inside the document directory.

Comment: Thank you. But, this is removing all the files in the document directory.

Comment: How can this be possible.First ensure that you make correct path or not.also you have more than one file in document directory.

Comment: Are you making a directory inside document directory or simply add file in document directory.

Comment: If it helps you then it need an upvote and if it short your problem then acceptance of ans is required.

Comment: Actually, when I touch the zip file, it will create a temporary directory in the document directory itself and gets extracted there. So, when I use removeItemAtPath: in the viewWillDisAppear: and call the RootViewController again in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath:, it creates and removes the temporary directory at the next second. This is my problem.

Comment: You need to setUp you code properly.use edited one it helps you to slove your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the custom back button on Navigation Bar. Create the method, which will fire on click event of Back button.